# Changing the font in a PDF

Tags: python, pdf, fonts

I have a repository of PDF documents, and most of the text contained in these documents are formatted in Comic Sans. I would like to change this to something similar to Arial. ***The original font is embedded in the document.*** I haven't found any existing tool to do this for me (I'm on Linux), and I wonder if it's possible to do it programmaticaly. A Python library would be perfect, but a library in any programming language would do.

**In which library will I be able to substitute fonts with the least effort? And which parts of the API would I use?**

Comment: I have no solution. But you will need to keep to a font that use exactly the same dimensions. If it's for example is a wider font, it won't make a new line if the line is not long enough, instead it will reach longer out to the right (hope you understand despite my limited knowledge of english)

Comment: Have you tried PDFedit it even has some scritping capabilities (don't know if thwy are enough for this though)

Comment: Not only the same individual widths but if kerning is used, the same glyph pairs should require the same kerning. Essentially, therefore, replacing fonts will make things look ugly unless unless the fonts were designed to replace each other.

Answer (score 1):

There are commercial tools that can do this - one of which is pdfToolbox from callas software *(warning - I'm affiliated with this company)*.

However - even though this functionality exists and is sometimes used - the results are often completely undesirable and I have not seen many contexts where it is used on more than very specific files. And usually with limited success. To the point where this replacement is only available as a manual operation in the tool I mentioned - and not in automatic mode.

Depending on how complex these files are, you would probably have better success to extract all text from the documents into something like RTF, do whatever manipulation you need to do there and regenerate PDF afterwards. Sounds like a roundabout way but I'm guessing the result will be better in most cases...

Comment: <rant mini="true">And that is the crux of my objection to pre-paginated electronic documents like PDF.</rant>

Comment: ;) @PeterWone Mainly to the inappropriate use of such document. And to people throwing away the sources those PDFs were generated from... The existing contents of PDFs simply are not meant to be changed, they are meant to be re-generated then.

Comment: @PeterWone: talk to someone who has to maintain a library of electronic documents (whether for artistic reasons or legal) and has to be sure that those documents absolutely, under no circumstances whatsoever, do not change... Or to someone who designs a piece that is going to be printed in three places in the world and must be sure all 5 million printed pieces look exactly the same. That is what PDF was meant for and excels at. Editing a PDF file can be done but - well - frankly is an aberration of the file format...